# IPhone Development - UIDatePicker date from NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uidatepicker

I'm trying to set the date of a UIDatePicker but I the month is everytime "January"(01). I tryed to use "MM" and "LL", but both of them are not working.

My code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];;
    NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2019-09-11"];   
    [datePicker setDate:anyDate];

    [dateFormat release];
```

}

Thanks in advance,

Claudio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mac's and iPhones](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) use the [Unicode Date Formatting](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

So your code should be:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
[super viewDidLoad];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"];;
NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2019-09-11"];   
[datePicker setDate:anyDate];

[dateFormat release];
}
```

Your data formatter used

- 'YYYY' - "Year (of "Week of Year"), used in ISO year-week calendar. May differ from calendar year." (whatever that means...)
- 'DD' - "Day of year" which is most likely why it gives you the January result.

Comment: guys `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"` this the one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a warning on the setDate call?

[It looks like the signature is "setDate:animated:"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDatePicker/setDate:animated:)

What happens when you do:

```
[datePicker setDate:anyDate animated:NO];
```

?